# How to get all the text inside an XML tag using XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, tcl, xpathnavigator

I have this sort of tags in an XML:

```
<command name="config">config show</command>
```

For example, to read that one with xpath I do:

```
//command[@name='config']
```

but this outs two strings: "config" and "show". I would like to be able to get a unique string: "config show".

I tried `/text()` and `/node()` but didn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

```
<command name="check_config">config show</command>
```

this XPath,

```
//command[@name='check_config']
```

selects all `command` elements in the document with a `@name` attribute value equal to `'config'`; in this case, only the element shown above:

```
<command name="check_config">config show</command>
```

Should this element be evaluated in the context that automatically converts to a string, or should you force such a conversion via the `string()` function,

```
string(//command[@name='check_config'])
```

it will be converted to the string value of that element,

```
config show
```

which is a single string, not two.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what it worked was:

```
//command[@name='check_config']/text()
```

I think I was doing something wrong in the syntax when I tried the function text() before! :)